# What coordinate system produces this particular form of the line element of de Sitter spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geometry, de-sitter-spacetime

To save space, all the symbols and conventions are adopted from  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_space) Wikipedia article.

We know that the line element of $n$ dimensional de Sitter space in static coordinates is

$$ds^2=-\bigg(1-\frac{r^2}{a^2}\bigg) dt^2+\bigg(1-\frac{r^2}{a^2}\bigg)^{-1} dr^2+r^2 d \Omega^2_{n-2}$$

My professor told me that $d \Omega_{n-2}$ does not necessarily stand for the $n-2$ sphere embedded in $n-1$ flat space, but rather any maximally symmetric space.

Is this true? What is the coordinate transformation that produces the above metric, but with $d \Omega$ standing for the $n-2$ Euclidean metric?